# Does bending the neck have any long term adverse effects?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

With electric guitars, it's a common technique to bend the neck of the guitar with your hands to produce a subtle pitch change. It is often used with guitars without a whammy bar. Are there any noticeable side effects that come with doing this too much over time? Would this technique weaken the neck and cause it to [snap](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxwXkt_M_-g) eventually?

Comment: Do not do this with an instrument you consider valuable. It is abuse.

Comment: Looks like the neck of guitar in the linked video will suffer long term adverse effects. :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen a nylon strung acoustic guitar neck snap doing this but an steel strung guitar has a truss rod strengthening the neck. However you may damage the neck anyway, or break the fixing to the body.

I do it on my warlock, occasionally but I keep it very minor. I would suggest not bending too far.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in that video it was the body that broke, not the neck. Also, this guitar didn't seem to be really great quality. I remember Tommy Emmanuel commenting on his neck-bending in a piece (on a Martin western guitar): "don't try that on a chinese instrument!".

You certainly won't be able to break the body of an electric guitar, but the neck or headstock... it's certainly possible.

Comment: What seems to give first on an electric is the join between the neck and body:-/

Comment: @DrMayhem Any difference you experience between bolt-on vs. neck through guitars in this regard?

Comment: Not in terms of how much force is required. I just don't have enough data. But in terms of damage,  it is much easier to repair the join of a bolt-on than a through-neck.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I was friends with [Adrian Belew](http://www.adrianbelew.net), and I remember hearing him say that he once ruined the neck on a Stratocaster after repeated bending. But he kept on using this technique on other Strats.